# How to delete dangling \n in a list created in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, replace

So I do this first:

```
list1 = open("file1.txt").readlines()
```

After this I do this:

```
list2 = open("file2.txt").readlines()
```

Now I zip them together and make a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

When I enter

```
dictionary
```

back into the terminal I get a huge dictionary, but list1 and list2 elements end in a `\n`. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strip` to remove trailing newlines.

```
list1 = [l.strip() for l in open('file1.txt')]
list2 = [l.strip() for l in open('file2.txt')]
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 5-minutes.